# Youtube subtitles not showing for embeded video - even the button is missing

Tags: video, youtube, embed, youtube-iframe-api, subtitle

For all videos with subtitles are missing (even the button) when you embed the video in iframe (directly or by API)

The google-example:
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

If you click "watch on youtube" there is an "subtitle"-Button, that is missing in the embedded view.
I tried the parameters cc_load_policy, cc_lang_pref and other stuff, but nothing works...

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that something changed between yesterday and today as I just posted the following question today:

[youtube-iframe-api closed captioning troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528683/youtube-iframe-api-closed-captioning-troubles)

Someone also pointed out code got changed YESTERDAY on the IFrame Player API.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Revision_History

Answer (score 1):

Experiencing the same problem with our embedded videos on all browser platforms. Problem was first noticed on 6/13/17 on our end. The CC option is missing in all embedded videos despite the .srt files being available and having been working as expected previously.

I hope YouTube gets this straightened out quickly. We are an international company of over 100,000 employees and we have already received feedback from hearing-impaired users that it has rendered our videos unusable.

Answer (score 1):

We're facing the same issue. On further inspection it seems the captions module is no longer provided to embeds.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was a temporary bug by youtube... the subtitles are working again in embedded videos since 15.06.2017...